# How to consume data about drupal contributed modules?

Tags: feeds, community-official-site

Is there a feed or feeds that expose data about all drupal contributed modules? I want to consume drupal.org data about modules in a certain category e.g. https://drupal.org/project/modules?f[0]=im_vid_3%3A59

I would love to get the catagories information e.g "Categories: Actively maintained, Under active development, Administration, Modules, Developer, Site Navigation"

I've seen http://drupal.org/node/63589, but the "Compatible with Drupal core 7.x" (http://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/103/0/feed) only lists about 72 ftp urls when I load it in a web browser.  That is not all of the D7 modules...

I also looked at the About page on http://drupalmodules.com for clues about how they get the data, but didn't find anything useful.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you do:

1. https://drupal.org/project/modules/categories
2. click on the More link for the Category which you want in your feed
3. Look at the taxonomy id number at the end of the url e.g. https://drupal.org/project/modules?f[0]=im_vid_3%3A56
4. construct your feed url like this: https://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/56/0/feed

Answer (score 0):

While it is not an rss feed, there is this page:

http://drupal.org/project/usage

which lists usage stats for all the modules **11899** of them. They each appear to have a page that has a bit more detail on it.